# how to make two columns are unique in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Good Day Friends,

I want to know that how to make two columns are unique in SQL server in the special manner as I explained below.

The Way I want :

```
------------------------- 
  User    | Friend      |  
-------------------------
  Stevan  | Johns     } 
  William | David     }This is how I want two columns to be unique.
```

The Way I don't Want :

```
-------------------------
  User    | Friend    | 
-------------------------
 Steven   | Johns     }   
 Johns    | Steven    }This must not allow.
```

Steven is a friend of  Johns 
So They are friends so  I don't want 
Johns to add a new row saying  Johns is a friend of Steven.

Steven add new row like this :

```
-------------------------
  User    | Friend    | 
-------------------------
 Steven   | Johns     }
```

I Don't want john to add a row again Like this

```
-------------------------
  User    | Friend    | 
-------------------------
 Steven   | Johns     }   
 Johns    | Steven    }
```

I hop my question is clear,  IF someone know a good answer for this , please help me.
Thanks in advance for any answer

Comment: So, there's nothing special about the `User` column vs the `Friend` column?

Comment: Actully I want only one Friend to make the friend ship. Not both friends

Comment: where user ="x" OR user="y" and friend="x" OR friend ="y"; when it returns true do nothing else do a insert. [Hope name is unique here].
Try to make it in SQL procedure / Trigger

Comment: I already tried that approach , but I prefer using a constrain, Is there any constrain to do this ?

Comment: I meant that the only reason a name appeared in `User` rather than `Friend` was that they were the person to do the insert first - if the friend had performed the insert first (so the names were the other way around), it wouldn't result in either of them being treated any differently, would it? (See my answer - where the first suggestion involves forcing the first name in the table to be `<` the second name - but this is only valid if we can (if required) switch the names before insertion)

Comment: @user2249029: There may be possibility for duplication of name. May be two Johns. if u names are unique u can move on.. else make some id for each people of unique type.

Comment: User or Friend columns are not unique itself but  they are unique as a combination of both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The straightforward way to do this (all else being equal) is to insist that the value in the first column always sort earlier than the value in the second column:

```
CREATE TABLE Friends (
    Party1 varchar(20) not null,
    Party2 varchar(20) not null,
    constraint CK_Friend_Parties CHECK (Party1 < Party2),
    constraint CK_Friends_Unique UNIQUE (Party1,Party2)
)
```

If you're unable to accommodate this change (which is odd, because it then suggests that the relationship isn't symmetric), you can enforce it via an indexed view:

```
create table dbo.T1 (
    Party1 varchar(20) not null,
    Party2 varchar(20) not null
)
go
create view dbo.V1
with schemabinding
as
    select
        CASE WHEN Party1 < Party2 THEN Party1 else Party2 END as NormParty1,
        CASE WHEN Party1 < Party2 THEN Party2 else Party1 END as NormParty2
    from
        dbo.T1
go
create unique clustered index IX_V1 on dbo.V1 (NormParty1,NormParty2)
go
insert into dbo.T1 (Party1,Party2) values ('Steven','John')
go
insert into dbo.T1 (Party1,Party2) values ('John','Steven')
```

The final insert above generates an error. Note that, for most intents, you ignore the view `V1` - it only exists to enforce this constraint (when I use such tables, I usually prefix their name with `DRI_` to make it clear that it wasn't really created to be queried.

Answer (score -1):

i think,because a primary key won't work, you will have to use a  trigger to check if the line allready exist.

Comment: the grammar was right, it was a complex sentence. if you want to be a grammar Nazi, be sure before correcting someone.
I made it simpler for non-native English speakers